# Display data on stacked bars of nvd3-multi-bar-chart

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using **nvd3-multi-bar-chart** for displaying a graph in my application. An example chart would be like below[image]

I have used the following directive for generating graphs:
[NVD3 Multibar chart](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html)

Everything is working good and the charts are also displaying well. But my problem is, I need to display the data on the bar like below
[image]

I have referred the following links before asking this question but did not helped me in solving my requirement
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242620/displaying-a-single-series-multi-bar-chart-using-nvd3-library), [Link 2](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203404/nvd3-stacked-bar-chart-with-discrete-values) and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Check this method: https://gist.github.com/topicus/217444acb4204f364e46

I'm using `angular-nvd3`, not `angular-nvd3-directives`, but I think it should work with a few changes.